# No module named 'scrapy': ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, scrapy, spyder

I'm scraping a random web page with Scrapy. I created the project, but when I tried to run my spider, it couldn't import scrapy.

This is my spider

```
import scrapy
import logging

# Spider for truecar.com
class TruecarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "truecar"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/tesla/model-3/']

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        all_listings = response.xpath('//div[@data-test="allVehicleListings"] > ul')

        for tesla in all_listings:
            aux = tesla.xpath('//div[@class="linkable card card-shadow vehicle-card"]')
            make_model = aux.xpath('@aria-label')#aux.css('::attr(aria-label)')
            year = make_model.xpath('@aria-label').get()
            model_raw = make_model.css('span.vehicle-header-make-model').get()
            model = model_raw[model_raw.find('>')+1:-7]. replace ('<! ----3"')
            tesla_data = {
                'url': 'http://truecar.com' + tesla.css('a::attr (href)').get(),
                'model': year + ' ' + model,
                'mileage': tesla.css('div[data-test="cardContent"] > div > div. text-truncate: :text').get(),
                'price': tesla.css('h4: :text').get(),
            }

            yield tesla_data
```

I have it installed through **pip install scrapy** so I tried through the terminal on VS Code to check if it exists.

This is what I got

[image: screenshot of VS Code]

I have python 3.10.1 and scrapy 2.7.1

Comment: That image is showing python 3.7 and you say you have python 3.10, so I'm guessing you've got multiple python installs and scrapy is installed for the wrong one. To install to python 3.10, try `python-3.10 -m pip install scrapy` or `pip3.10 install scrapy`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910393/53341

Comment: Actually, it looks like you installed to 3.10 but are trying to run it from 3.7, so try running python with `python3.10` instead of `python`. You'll also need to ensure your IDE (spider, vscode, whatever) is set up to use the correct python install.

Comment: How do I ensure that my IDE is set with the correct version? I think everything else is correct

Comment: Check the manual? https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment

Comment: And look at `venvs`, they will allow you to manage libraries more conveniently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@MatBailie's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75304179/no-module-named-scrapy-modulenotfounderror/75345055#comment132878622_75304179), it helped me to see that my python version on the IDE was wrong. I'm using VS Code and if any of you have the same problem you can check it here, on the blue bar below the terminal. If it doesn't appear, make sure you have Python extension and that it is reloaded:

[image]